# Setting select option with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following select:

```
<select id="select_produckt" class="form-control">
    <option id="select_default" selected="" value="0">Vælg produkt</option>
    <option value="1">NP 89,-</option>
    <option value="2">NN 89,-</option>
    <option value="3">NP 99,-</option>
    <option value="4">NN 99,-</option>
    <option value="5">NP 119,-</option>
    <option value="6">NN 119,-</option>
    <option value="7">NP 139,-</option>
    <option value="8">NN 139,-</option>
    <option value="9">NP 169,-</option>
    <option value="10">NN 169,-</option>
    <option value="11">NP 239,-</option>
    <option value="12">NN 239,-</option>
</select>
```

Now, I wish to simply set the value of the select with JavaScript (meaning that the options text will be shown).

I've tried the following:

```
$('#select_produckt').val(2)
```

This, however, just left the field blank.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

**Update**

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Excel_Data/getSale',
    data: {
        request: 'ajax',
        row_id: id,
        list_id: list_id
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#product_selection').removeClass('hidden');
        alert(parseInt(data))
        $('#select_produckt').val(""+data)
    }
});
```

Comment: Works fine.... http://jsfiddle.net/S4n3v/

Comment: Make sure your code is in the `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: Your JavaScript maybe has other errors preventing it from executing? The code you've shown works as @Anthony points out.

Comment: @AnthonyChu ive updated my code to match (the ajax call im making returns "2") but apperntly i keep getting nan

Comment: fixed it! apprently it was because it was an array :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#select_produckt').find('option')[2].selected = true;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qwJKV/